# Vlan Command Issues on Cisco Switches

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-catalyst, ieee-802.1x

I'm new to cisco equipment. I have GNS3 emulating an L3 switch whose image is "i86bi-linux-l3-adventerprisek9-15.5.2T.bin". I want to create a cable network with 802.1x and vlan authentication. For this I have been following a video. It starts after configuring the Radius server to type the command "conf t" and then "vlan 10" but when I type the command "vlan 10" it returns "% Invalid input detected at '^' marker." The "^" is below number 1. I wonder why I can't create the vlans if my image is from an L3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using **MultiLayer Switch(Image)**

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your answer by editing it to add more details to make it more useful both for the original poster and future users. Typically short answers like this could provide reasoning why you believe this is the answer, more explanation about the concepts mentioned, references/links to supporting resources, or applicable examples.

Comment: Try with another IOS image .Most of times due to bugs in images this of issues occurs